# How to exclude rows with double values in a SELECT statement

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird1.5

I have a table that has amongst other things an ID column and a parent ID column:

```
id |parentID
------------
 1 |  1
 2 |  1
 3 |  3
 4 |  3
 5 |  5
 6 |  5
```

So basically there is an entry with `id = parentID` and some entry with an `parentID` which is an `ID` from some other row. Sometimes the entries with `parentID <> id` are missing, but `id = parentID` are always there. My goal is to find all those `id = parentID` entries that don't have the corresponding `id <> parentID` entry. How can it be done in Firebird 1.5? Thank you!

Comment: What is your expect output for this sample data?

Answer (score 1):

You do it just the same way you do with any other tables: `left join` the tables (this time, the table with itself) and check for `null` (missing rows).

See it on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0&fiddle=0b7e8b6dfef36d6929121fc28b584fa2)*

> ```
> select rdb$get_context('SYSTEM', 'ENGINE_VERSION') as version
>      , rdb$character_set_name
> from rdb$database;
> ```
>
> ```
> VERSION | RDB$CHARACTER_SET_NAME                                                                                                      
> :------ | :---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> 3.0.5   | UTF8
> ```

> ```
> create table pool( id integer primary key, parentID integer not null)
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into pool
> select 1, 1 from rdb$database union all
> select 2, 1 from rdb$database union all
> select 3, 3 from rdb$database union all
> select 4, 3 from rdb$database union all
> select 5, 5 from rdb$database union all
> select 6, 5 from rdb$database union all
> select 7, 7 from rdb$database
> ```
>
> ```
> 7 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> select * from pool
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | PARENTID
> -: | -------:
>  1 |        1
>  2 |        1
>  3 |        3
>  4 |        3
>  5 |        5
>  6 |        5
>  7 |        7
> ```

> ```
> select p1.* from pool p1
> left join pool p2
>   on (p2.parentid = p1.parentid) and (p2.parentid <> p2.id)
> where (p1.parentid = p1.id)
>  and (p2.id is null)
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | PARENTID
> -: | -------:
>  7 |        7
> ```

> ```
> select p1.* from pool p1
> left join pool p2
>   on (p2.parentid = p1.id) and (p2.parentid <> p2.id)
> where (p1.parentid = p1.id)
>  and (p2.id is null)
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | PARENTID
> -: | -------:
>  7 |        7
> ```